# Rails, partials annotations, rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, annotations, haml, rubymine, yard

I have a Haml partial, which is rendered in a few templates, and requires specific local variables.

I want let know to other developers and IDE's (rubymine) know which local variable dependencies this partial/template has. For example `_actions.haml`:

```
- # @param [DigRulingService] ruling capability service
- # @param [Dig] dig entry object

- if ruling.ruler_removable?(dig)
  - name = ruling.related_ruling(dig).ruler.present_name
  = link_to("Remove #{name}", "#")

- if ruling.invite_cancelable?(dig)
  = link_to("Cancel request", "#")

- if ruling.able_to_invite?(dig)
  = link_to("Send new Invitation", "#")
```

But rubymine does not understand those comments, and highlights `ruling` and `dig` as undefined.

How I can it tell Tubymine about that local variables, for higlights thay methods as undefined(if not exists), and unhighlights thay as undefined?

Comment: AFAIK HAML has no notion of documenting template requirements, and I don't know of any pre-processor or IDE that extends itself to support that. It'd be handy, though! It might be worth checking the JetBrains forums (and several of their devs answer questions here) so maybe they'll have a better idea.

Comment: It's also worth submitting a request on the RubyMine's tracker specifying the expected and actual behaviour: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY

Comment: Sent. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-28237